# What is the Pragma Header? Caching pages.. and IE

Tags: php, caching, http-headers

So I am sending a header in php to cache my page (this integrates into our "CDN" (contendo/akamai) as well). I always use this pragma: cache header, I've seen various examples use it as well; however, I just checked fiddler to test traffic for this .net application we developed and it says:

> ```
> Legacy Pragma Header is present: cache
> !! Warning IE supports only an EXACT match of "Pragma: no-cache". IE will ignore the Pragma header if any other values are present.
> ...
> ```

I suppose that is ok. The rest of the response seems fine and to my specs. Here is my code:

```
function headers_for_page_cache($cache_length=600){
    $cache_expire_date = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $cache_length);
    header("Expires: $cache_expire_date");
    header("Pragma: cache");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=$cache_length");
    header("User-Cache-Control: max-age=$cache_length");
}
```

The question is does this matter? What does the pragma header even do? Do I need it? I checked the HTTP header spec documentation and it said it is implementation specific and the only Pragma that is enforced is "Pragma: no-cache".

Is this the best choice of headers to cache for a specific amount of time?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In a very simplified form, `Pragma:no-cache or Pragma:cache` are now "almost" obsolete ways of passing caching instructions to client implementations, specifically browers and proxies. The way the client implementation responds to Pragma headers vary which is why the specification says it is implementation specific.

The more modern way of `Cache-control` is what you can safely depend on, as almost all client implementations follow it rigidly.

Also, if you have both `Cache-control` and `Pragma` set for the same instruction, say caching, then `Cache-control` takes precedence.

This is an **excellent** article about everything related to Caching and I think it makes a very interesting and useful read: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: You weren't lying; the link provides a great read, and is very informative for beginners like me

Comment: rfc2616 states: "When the no-cache directive is present in a request message, an application SHOULD forward the request toward the origin server even if it has a cached copy of what is being requested." So this is a request header not a response header